# Fetching user freindly values from a lookup field

Tags: foreign-keys, parent-child, primary-key, apex, soql

I am trying to write a query in my apex trigger that will return a user friendly value.

```
Map<String, Order> order_1 = new Map<String, Order>([
Select Account.Name
From Order
]);

System.debug('Order 1: ' + order_1);
```

When I write the query in my trigger it returns some odd number letter combinations but when I write it in the query editor it returns something like "Toys R Us" for instance. Why does the query return the foreign key instead of the data when in my trigger but returns the actual account name in the query editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because passing a query into the Map constructor will use the record Id as the key. I think what your after is this:

```
Map<String, Order> order_1 = new Map<String, Order>();

for(Order o : [Select Account.Name From Order]) {
    order_1.put(o.Account.Name, o);
}

System.debug('Order 1: ' + order_1);
```